# Radio Button To Activate Another Radio Button On Separate Excel Sheet (Same Workbook)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a radio button on Sheet1 (module 1) and the code it currently has is:

```
Sub Sec1No 
    MsgBox "If There Are No IT Costs, Disregard Sheet2.", , "From Admin"
End Sub
```

I then have a different radio button on Sheet2 (module 2).

Is it possible that when a user clicks on the first radio button on sheet1, when they go to sheet2 the button is already clicked for them?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can call the second radio button by its name, just like you would any other subroutine:

```
Sub Sec1No 
    MsgBox "If There Are No IT Costs, Disregard Sheet2.", , "From Admin"
    Button2_Click 'replace this with the name of the button on Sheet 2
End Sub
```

That will run button 2's code when button 1 is clicked.